# Odd modal behavior with MaterializeCSS in Firefox

Tags: firefox, modal-dialog, materialize

I found a really strange behavior when using a Materialize CSS modal in Firefox (66.0.1). It works fine in Chrome (73.0.3683.86) and MS Edge (where do you find the version?). I'm using Windows 10. It does this with the modal demo in the official Materialize CSS website as well.

The problem seems to start if you display a modal with enough content so that it displays a vertical scrollbar. It needs to have links or buttons to see the problem I will describe. You can simulate this by resizing Firefox so that its vertical height is small enough to make the scrollbar appear. Now close the modal. Then resize the height of Firefox so that the modal will appear without scrollbars. Open the modal and hover over a link or button and any hover effect that should happen, does not. Click once on any link or button and nothing happens. Click a second time and it works properly.

And even odder, after opening the first modal with a scrollbar, you can open the second without a scrollbar and do nothing for about 15 seconds and then the links or buttons will work fine.

When this happened, I tried right-clicking on the button to "inspect the element" in the Firefox Inspector. Instead of getting the button, I got the modal overlay element behind it. Note that when this happens, the overlay is not above the button or any of the modal content. It's not a z-index problem. To see whether it was a problem with the overlay, I added an onOpenEnd() function to the modal options that would remove the overlay as soon as the modal opened. I had the same problem. When I tried again to open it in the inspector, I got whatever was behind the button. So it's almost like the modal isn't even there until I click on the modal first or wait for 15 seconds.

I then tried to add some code to the onOpenEnd() function that would give focus to the button, but no effect with that. I tried tabbing to the button, but that didn't work either.

Just before submitting this I found another piece of the puzzle. As I said, hovering over the buttons when this is happening will not show the usual hover pointer. But if I hover above and a bit to the left of the buttons, the cursor does change. When I click there, the color of the buttons does change like it's been clicked, but the action (closing the modal) does not happen. Hmmmmm....

If you want to test this out, go to the Materialize CSS webisite and open the page for modals. (https://materializecss.com/modals.html) Reduce the vertical size of Firefox so that when you open the demo modal it has a vertical scrollbar. Now close the modal. Resize Firefox back to normal vertical height and open the modal again. Hover over the Agree or Disagree buttons and you won't get the pointer cursor. Try click once and nothing happens. Click again and the modal will close. Or wait the 15 seconds and then the buttons work.

Most of my users will have the modal open for more than 15 seconds so it's not a big problem. But sometimes they will open it just to check something and then want to close it. Sure they can click twice, but I'd rather it work properly. Chrome and Edge work fine. Firefox doesn't. Can anyone think of what is causing this and whether there is anything I can do in my code to make it work properly? Thanks.